# Cross-app session persistence (thoughtbot/clearance) with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, subdomain, clearance

I have a web app installed in example.com that uses Clearance as the authentication gem and I am currently working on a stand-alone Rails app in jobs.example.com.

I am wondering if Clearance has built in configurations to user session persistence across Rails apps hosted on different subdomains. Do I need to import the user authentication details from the original app (example.com) via an API and manipulate cookies to do so?

Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this with clearance via the use of the `cookie_domain` configration (see documentation) and synchronizing the user data required by each system, but this is almost assuredly going to be a real big pain. If the apps must be separate with separate databases then you may want to investigate making your main app an Oauth Provider and have jobs be an Oauth consumer. Auth itself would live in your main app and when the jobs app needs authentication it would delegate to the main app. Assuming auth checks out, the main app would pass you back information about the user.